# Github merge another branch to your local master branch

Tags: git

I am new to git and github, i cloned a project's master branch to my local machine, i want to know how i can merge another remote branch to the branch i have on my machine.

Comment: Cloning a project and branches are somewhat orthogonal from one another.  Do you have code from one project that you want to merge into a *different* project?  Help us understand here.

Comment: It's the same project i cloned the master branch i want to know how i can merge the code from another branch to the clone i have on my local machine.

Comment: ...You have the branches already - look at the output of `git branch -vvv`.  I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply merge it.

```
git fetch
git checkout <mybranch>
git merge <remote_branch>
```